# How to fetch data using procedure in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am using procedure first time.How can I fetch data using procedure.I created this procedure in sql file.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `GetUserProfile`(IN p_user_id INT, IN p_enabled BIT)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
# prepare init params
if p_user_id = 0 then
set p_user_id = null;
end if;

select  parent_user_id
      ,user_id
      ,Last_name
      ,First_name
      ,email as Email_address
      ,mobile as Phone
from    app_users
where   app_user_id = IFNULL(p_user_id, user_id)
```

and     enabled = IFNULL(p_enabled, enabled);

then How can I fetch the user detail through PHP like First_name,Last_name etc.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you can use **sqlsrv_connect** function to connect to SQL Server db, use **sqlsrv_prepare** function to call *tsql function* and **$params** args and, at last, use one of the **sqlsrv_fetch_*** function to retrieve data.

see instruction on this page:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I want to know method from which data could be access using procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) to execute a mysql stored procedure and access the results.

See the examples [on this page from the PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). In particular example #4

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
?>
```

and example #5

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_takes_string_returns_string(?)");
$value = 'hello';
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $value\n";
?>
```

If you haven't used PDO before I'd suggest browsing through the documentation, [creating a new PDO object](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) to manipulate a dabase is as simple as:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```